# Running a script with arguments from within another python script

Tags: python

In Jupyter, this can be achieved with the `%run` line magic. Like this:

```
%run -i somescript.py -f -b
```

But that magic does not work from within a python script file. I tried this:

```
os.system("python3 -i somescript.py -f -b")
```

A further complication is that I want to use a variable, like this:

```
%run -i somescript.py -f $LINE -b
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using subprocess ?

That is probably not the best answer, but you can call bash from python script, which calls another python script

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["echo", "Hello world!"])
```

Comment: In your example, doesn't `.split()` cause issues because you have split it into 3 elements when it should be `["echo", "'Hello world!'"]`?